# A function inside a struct C++

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct segment{
    int _gcd;
    int _count;
    segment(){
        _gcd=0;
        _count=0;
    }
    segment(int val)
    {
        _gcd=val;
        _count=1;
    }
    void mergee(segment left,segment right)
    {
        _count=0;
       _gcd=gcd(left._gcd,right._gcd);
       if(_gcd==left._gcd)
       {
           _count+=left._count;
       }
       if(_gcd==right._gcd)
       {
           _count+=right._count;
       }
    }
}seg[4*N];
```

I sought a solution to Ant Colony problem in CodeForces and stumbled on https://w84iit.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/ant-colony-solutioncodeforces/. The thing that confused me the most was this `struct` part. Is that a declaration of function inside a struct? I also see that there's function overloading in `struct` too. I am not quite familiar with a function inside `struct`, as Google search also shows that it's more common to pass `struct`s to an outer function. How do struct functions work? Can they only modify the variables declared inside the `struct`? Can I return something? The example above only used the function inside `struct` to modify its variable values.

Comment: Functions inside structs was the reason C++ was invented in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function inside a class is called a non-static member function.

It has an implied object parameter that is accessible through `this`.

When called, the object parameter is on the left of the `.` in class member access:

```
struct x {
    int data_member;
    int f(int i){
        return data_member+i;
    }
};

x y;
y.f(10);
```

equivalent to:

```
struct x {
    int data_member;
};

int f(x* _this, int i) {
   return _this->data_member + i;
}

x y;
f(&y,10);
```

Comment: struct is missing ; and return value of f should be int. Nice answer.

Comment: Isn't a function defined inside a struct also an inline function?

Comment: @user3366592 it is.

Comment: @user3366592 Also, not told in the answer is the difference in name look up.

Answer (score 9):

In C++, the `struct` of C is generalised to a class.

In fact the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is the default access of data members, and inheritance.

So yes, a `struct` can contain functions, just like a `class` can.

Comment: Or, simpler said: `class` and `struct` both declare a class, and imply only syntactic differences. That's it.

Comment: @Pi: Indeed; it's an answer to a slightly different question.

Comment: @Pi: Yes, let's give it another open-close cycle.

Comment: With public inheritance by default, the struct has won for me.